# Is there a spin-1/2 hadron composed entirely of up quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle, color-charge

I am curious to know if there exists a spin-1/2 hadron that is composed of three up quarks. I understand that in quantum chromodynamics, baryons are formed of three quarks, each carrying a distinct color charge to ensure color neutrality. Given that the Pauli Exclusion Principle necessitates distinct quantum states for each quark, is there a configuration where three up quarks could form a color-neutral baryon with a total spin of 1/2?

I am aware of the Δ++ baryon, where three up quarks with aligned spins result in a total spin of 3/2. However, I am wondering if there is a known baryon configuration with three up quarks that results in a total spin of 1/2.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109910/